# How to set some Data properly into Database

Tags: android, database, list, android-studio

I have a task object that I would like to track time spent on. I am running a timer counting up for a variable in the task, but whenever I go to update the task inside the database it seems like it somehow gets set back to null even after I confirm that it updates. I was thinking that maybe I am not understanding the database class completely, and making the context that I am calling the database on somehow affects the data inside. Is there any reason that my data is being set to null?

Comment: You use SQLite or something else?

Comment: Yeah I use SQLite. It just seems like no matter how I change it the data doesn't save well. I think I discovered why I was getting null values though (I was passing a value as parcelable across activities and somehow I guess that messed it up). Now I am trying to find out why I am updating data to the database all over the place and never getting data updated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured this out. The problem was that I was creating multiple instances of the database in one activity. Also, I was using a service that was meant to share data across activities that both affect the data within the database in specific ways. When I passed between these activities, the application was essentially swapping between different instances of the same database, and therefore never really saved the data correctly and led to some weird behavior.

The moral of the story is that you should create one global database for your activity, and try to share the same database between two activities attempting to manipulate the same data.